# Network request in a loop crashes the application

Tags: ios, swift, loops, network-programming, grand-central-dispatch

I have a bug that I do not understand why.
My problem is that I have three functions whose names are sendCourse, sendRequire, sendStep.
The first function sendCourse is simple. This function is just a basic network query.
The sendRequire and sendStep functions are similar. They contain a for loop that iterates an array to send each element of the array to the server. In this function, it is necessary to wait until the previous network request is complete (that the element is sent to the server) to send the next element of the array.
Finally, I have another method called sendRecipe. This method executes sendCourse, sendRequire, sendStep. senRecipe must wait for sendCourse to complete. When sendCourse is finished, the sendRecipe function must execute sendRequire. Then sendRecipe must wait until sendRequire is finished to execute sendStep.
Finally, I have a button that calls sendRecipe.
When I click on the button my application crashes.
Here is my code:

```
    private func sendCourse(success: @escaping(() -> Void), errorHandling: @escaping((String) -> Void)) {
        let dataCourse:[String:String] = [
            "name":self.course.name,
            "course_type_id":String(self.course.type.id),
            "country_code":self.course.country.countryCode,
            "dishes_number":String(self.course.dishesNumber),
            "description":self.course.description
        ]
        APIManager.sharedInstance.put(action: .courses, data: dataCourse, onSuccess: {(responseCode, data) -> Void in
            if responseCode == 201 {
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                if let course = try? jsonDecoder.decode(Courses.self, from: data) {
                    self.course = course
                    success()
                } else {
                    errorHandling("service unavailable")
                }
            } else {
                errorHandling("service unavailable")
            }
        }, onFailure: {(error) -> Void in
            errorHandling(error.localizedDescription)
        })
    }

    private func sendRequire(success: @escaping(() -> Void), errorHandling: @escaping((String) -> Void)) {
        let requireGroup = DispatchGroup()
        var fail = false
        for require in requires {
            if fail == true {
                break
            }
            requireGroup.enter()
            let dataRequire:[String:String] = [
                "course_id":String(self.course.id!),
                "ingredient_id":String(require.ingredient.id),
                "quantity":String(format: "%f", require.quantity)
            ]
            APIManager.sharedInstance.put(action: .requires, data: dataRequire, onSuccess: {(responseCode, data) -> Void in
                if responseCode == 201 {
                    requireGroup.leave()
                    success()
                } else {
                    requireGroup.leave()
                    fail = true
                    errorHandling("Service unavailable")
                }
            }, onFailure: {(error) -> Void in
                requireGroup.leave()
                fail = true
                errorHandling(error.localizedDescription)})
        }
        requireGroup.wait()
    }
    private func sendStep(success: @escaping(() -> Void), errorHandling: @escaping((String) -> Void)) {
        let stepGroup = DispatchGroup()
        var fail = false
        for (index, step) in self.steps.enumerated() {
            if fail == true {
                break
            }
            stepGroup.enter()
            var previousStepId=0
            if index == 0 {
                previousStepId = 0
            } else {
                previousStepId = steps[index-1].id!
            }
            let dataStep:[String:String] = [
                "course_id":String(self.course.id!),
                "description":step.description,
                "duration_hours":String(step.durationHours),
                "duration_minutes":String(step.durationMinutes),
                "duration_seconds":String(step.durationSeconds),
                "previous_step_id":String(previousStepId)

            ]
            APIManager.sharedInstance.put(action: .steps, data: dataStep, onSuccess: {(responseCode, data) -> Void in
                if responseCode == 201 {
                    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                    if let step = try? jsonDecoder.decode(Step.self, from: data) {
                        self.steps[index] = step
                        stepGroup.leave()
                        success()
                    } else {
                        fail = true
                        errorHandling("service unavailable")
                        stepGroup.leave()
                    }
                } else {
                    fail = true
                    errorHandling("service unavailable")
                    stepGroup.leave()
                }
            }, onFailure: {(error) -> Void in
                errorHandling(error.localizedDescription)
                fail = true
                stepGroup.leave()
            })
            stepGroup.wait()
        }
    }
    func sendRecipe(errorHandling: @escaping((String) -> Void)) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).sync {
            self.sendCourse(success: {}, errorHandling: errorHandling)
        }
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).sync {
            self.sendRequire(success: {}, errorHandling: errorHandling)
        }
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).sync {
            self.sendStep(success: {}, errorHandling: errorHandling)
        }
    }
here is the code of the button:
    @IBAction func doneBarButtonItemTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        recipe?.steps = steps
        recipe?.sendRecipe(errorHandling: {(error) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "dismiss", style: .default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
    }
```

here is the capture of my screen when the app crash: 
[capture of Xcode when the app crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORuNj.png)
Thank you in advanced

Comment: What are the details of the crash?  What is he message in the console? What line does it crash on?

Comment: Also, sendRecipe won't do what you want it to. Even though you are dispatching each of the `send...` functions synchronously, those functions are themselves synchronous, so all of there is no waiting between each step.

Comment: @paulw11 you can detail more please

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: 
Here is the code which should work:

```
private func sendCourse(success: @escaping(() -> Void), errorHandling: @escaping((String) -> Void)) {
    let dataCourse:[String:String] = [
        "name":self.course.name,
        "course_type_id":String(self.course.type.id),
        "country_code":self.course.country.countryCode,
        "dishes_number":String(self.course.dishesNumber),
        "description":self.course.description
    ]
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).sync {
    APIManager.sharedInstance.put(action: .courses, data: dataCourse, onSuccess: {(responseCode, data) -> Void in
        print(responseCode, String(data:data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        if responseCode == 201 {
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let course = try? jsonDecoder.decode(Courses.self, from: data) {
                self.course = course
                success()
            } else {
                errorHandling("service unavailable")
            }
        } else {
            errorHandling("service unavailable")
        }
    }, onFailure: {(error) -> Void in
        errorHandling(error.localizedDescription)
    })
    }
}

private func sendRequire(success: @escaping(() -> Void), errorHandling: @escaping((String) -> Void)) {
    let requireGroup = DispatchGroup()
    var fail = false
    for (index, require) in requires.enumerated() {
        if fail == true {
            break
        }
        requireGroup.enter()
        let dataRequire:[String:String] = [
            "course_id":String(self.course.id ?? 0),
            "ingredient_id":String(require.ingredient.id),
            "quantity":String(format: "%f", require.quantity)
        ]
        APIManager.sharedInstance.put(action: .requires, data: dataRequire, onSuccess: {(responseCode, data) -> Void in
            print(responseCode, String(data:data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            if responseCode == 201 {
                requireGroup.leave()
            } else {
                fail = true
                errorHandling("Service unavailable")
            }
        }, onFailure: {(error) -> Void in
            fail = true
            errorHandling(error.localizedDescription)
        })
        requireGroup.wait()
        if index==requires.count-1 {
            success()
        }
    }
}
private func sendStep(success: @escaping(() -> Void), errorHandling: @escaping((String) -> Void)) {
    let stepGroup = DispatchGroup()
    var fail = false
    for (index, step) in self.steps.enumerated() {
        if fail == true {
            break
        }
        stepGroup.enter()
        var previousStepId=0
        if index == 0 {
            previousStepId = 0
        } else {
            previousStepId = steps[index-1].id!
        }
        let dataStep:[String:String] = [
            "course_id":String(self.course.id ?? 0),
            "description":step.description,
            "duration_hours":String(step.durationHours),
            "duration_minutes":String(step.durationMinutes),
            "duration_seconds":String(step.durationSeconds),
            "previous_step_id":String(previousStepId)

        ]
        APIManager.sharedInstance.put(action: .steps, data: dataStep, onSuccess: {(responseCode, data) -> Void in
            print(responseCode, String(data:data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            if responseCode == 201 {
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                if let step = try? jsonDecoder.decode(Step.self, from: data) {
                    self .steps[index] = step
                    stepGroup.leave()
                } else {
                    fail = true
                    errorHandling("service unavailable")
                }
            } else {
                fail = true
                errorHandling("service unavailable")
            }
        }, onFailure: {(error) -> Void in
            errorHandling(error.localizedDescription)
            fail = true
        })
        stepGroup.wait()
        if index==steps.count-1 {
            success()
        }
    }
}
func sendRecipe(errorHandling: @escaping((String) -> Void)) {
    let recipeGroup = DispatchGroup()
    recipeGroup.enter()
    self.sendCourse(success: {recipeGroup.leave()}, errorHandling: errorHandling)
    recipeGroup.wait()
    recipeGroup.enter()
    self.sendRequire(success: {recipeGroup.leave()}, errorHandling: errorHandling)
    recipeGroup.wait()
    recipeGroup.enter()
    self.sendStep(success: {recipeGroup.leave()}, errorHandling: errorHandling)
}
```